# When does a symmetric matrix have repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I understand that for each of the $N$ eigenvalues (regardless of repeated or not) of an $N\times N$ symmetric matrix, the algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity are equal. This means if an eigenvalue is repeated $M$ times, then we have exactly $M$ orthogonal eigenvectors associated with this eigenvalue.

What I haven't figured out are:

1. Each entry of my $400\times400$ symmetric matrix is from $0$ to $1$ (both inclusive). I notice that many eigenvalues crowd at $0$, $-1$ and $1$, if they are not actually equal. On the other hand, eigenvalues elsewhere are well dispersed (figure below). Does this tell me anything about my symmetric matrix?

[image]

2. In fact, entries of my matrix distribute weirdly between $0$ and $1$ in the sense that the predominant majority of the values (after I exlude zero entries) distribute between $0$ and $0.1$ (figure below). Maybe this has something to do with the result above?

[image]

3. If this is not a numerical issue (i.e., the eigenvalues are really repeated), when does a symmetric matrix have repeated eigenvalues? Or what can we say about such a matrix?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/05/16/the-curious-case-of-random-eigenvalues.html)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the article, which seems to suggest it's unsurprising to get a lot of eigenvalues centered around $0$. But I think the reason why so many eigenvalues clustered towards the two extremes seems still unclear. Thanks again!

Comment: You are right, Wigner's semicircle law (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WignersSemicircleLaw.html) mentioned in the article does not account for your very "peaky" distribution (three peaks in $-1,0$ and $1$). Could it be that you have a bias in the generation of your symmetric matrices, which would not be as general as you think ? Could you provide your code ?