# When do symmetric matrices with rotated rows have repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetry

When do symmetric matrices with rotated rows have repeated eigenvalues? By *rotated rows* I mean each row is a rotation of a previous row.

In $\mathbb R^n$, the matrix $S$ where $$S_{ij} = \begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } i = j\\ \frac 1 2 &\text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ has $n - 1$ repeated eigenvalues, as shown by computation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848863/find-the-lengths-of-the-principal-axes-of-the-ellipsoid-sum-i-leq-j-x-ix-j).

Does this generalize? Can we state conditions where matrices that resemble $S$ have $k$ repeated eigenvalues?

See also [When does a symmetric matrix have repeated eigenvalues?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870209/when-does-a-symmetric-matrix-have-repeated-eigenvalues) , which is related, but does not address matrices of this nature.

Comment: What are "rotated rows"?

Comment: all matrices of that kind have $n-1$ repeated eigenvalues since they can be written as $cI + E$ where $I$ is the identity, $c$ is a scalar and $E$ is a rank one matrix

Comment: @TedShifrin Updated

Comment: see for example
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689111/find-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix-with-ones-in-the-diagonal-and-all-the-other-el

Comment: If you mean that the first row may be any vector, then "matrices with rotated rows" are well-known and they are called Circulant Matrices, whose eigenvalues are easy to compute, but they are almost always distinct
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: @Exodd You have some valuable points.  Would you consider assembling and expanding them into an answer?